# Creating a more consistant, randomly generated, world space for a text-based RPG

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, oop

Currently, I can create a randomized world within a 2-D array. However, I feel it is too random. Here is the class I'm currently working with:

`from random import randint, choice, randrange`

```
class WorldSpace(object):
    def __init__(self, row, col, world_array):
        self.row = row  # Number of lists to be created.
        self.col = col  # Number of indexes inside of each row.
        self.world_array = world_array
```

The `WorldSpace` method that creates the world:

```
@classmethod
def generate(cls, autogen):
    print 'Starting world generation...'
    print
    if autogen is True:
        row_amt = 75
        col_amt = 75

    else:
        row_amt = input('Please specify row length of world array.: ')
        col_amt = input('Please specify column length of world array.: ')
        if (row_amt or col_amt) == 0:
            print 'Invalid world values!'
            cls.generateWorld(False)

    world_array = [[' ']*col_amt for _ in xrange(row_amt)]
    print 'Created world...'

    return cls(row_amt, col_amt, world_array)
```

A method that modifies the world -- currently only creates `forests` though in my full segment of code, a series of oceans and mountains are formed as well:

```
def modify_world(self, autogen):
    if autogen is True:
        # Forests:
        count = randint(6, 10)
        while count > 0:
            a = randint(1, (self.row / randint(2, 6)))
            b = randint(1, (self.col / randint(2, 6)))
            row_val = randint(5, self.row)
            count_val = randint(5, 15)
            self.genLine_WObj(a, b, row_val, 't', count_val)
            count -=1

    print('\n'.join([''.join(['{:1}'.format(item) for item in row])
      for row in self.world_array]))
    inp = input('')
    if inp != '':
        return
```

And the method that actually creates the `forest` tiles:

```
def genLine_WObj(self, a, b, row_val, char, count):
    # 'genLine_WObj' - Generate Line(like) world object.
    # Used to place lines of certain characters with psuedo-randomized
    # width and length onto the world array.
    while count != 0:
        row_col_dict = {row_val: (a, b)}
        for row in row_col_dict.keys():
            startPos, endPos = row_col_dict[row]

            for i in range(startPos, endPos):
                self.world_array[row][i] = char

        b += choice([0, 1])
        a += choice([0, 0, 0, 0, 1])

        row_val -= 1
        count -= 1
```

Now to actually run the program:

```
world = WorldSpace.generate(True)
world.modify_world(True)
```

However, while the works ~20-30% of the time, sometimes it will generate small forests, or small pairs of `t` characters, when it should be creating forests all around the map.  How can I improve my code to make the randomized generation more consistent?

Comment: You haven't explained the goal.  Something cannot be both randomized and consistent - that's a contradiction in terms.  What does "small pairs" mean?  Also your code has problems: for example, look at the first three lines in the while loop of genLine - you create a one-element dictionary and "iterate" over it (the loop runs only once), then use the key to look up the value that you just explicitly assigned to it, and assign *that* to two new variables.  None of that code actually does anything.  I suggest you post your code to CodeReview and get help to clean it up.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:

1. Sometimes your `a` is bigger than your `b` and forest is not generated.
2. All your forests tend to be at the left side of map.

Inline comments are added for changed lines.

```
def modify_world(self, autogen):
    if autogen is True:
        # Forests:
        count = randint(6, 10)
        while count > 0:
            a = randrange(self.col)           # begin of forest
            width = self.col / randint(2, 6)  # initial width of forest
            b = int(a + width)                # end of forest
            row_val = randint(5, self.row)
            count_val = randint(5, 15)
            self.genLine_WObj(a, b, row_val, 't', count_val)
            count -=1

    print('\n'.join([''.join(['{:1}'.format(item) for item in row])
      for row in self.world_array]))
    inp = input('')
    if inp != '':
        return


def genLine_WObj(self, a, b, row_val, char, count):
    # 'genLine_WObj' - Generate Line(like) world object.
    # Used to place lines of certain characters with psuedo-randomized
    # width and length onto the world array.
    while count != 0:
        row_col_dict = {row_val: (a, b)}
        for row in row_col_dict.keys():
            startPos, endPos = row_col_dict[row]

            for i in range(startPos, min(self.col, endPos)):  # added min
                self.world_array[row][i] = char

        b += choice([0, 1])
        a += choice([0, 0, 0, 0, 1])

        row_val -= 1
        count -= 1
```

And I would change `width` of forest to something mapsize-independent. E. g.:

```
width = randint(2, 15)
```

But that depends on your goals.